# What are the best practices for managing multiple users on an iPad app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

What are the best practices for setting up multi user functionality in an iPad app?

I am trying to start an ios project for iPad which will create new username, and password, as well as managing different users on a given device locally on the iPad in order to access the app itself. Something like what keeper does when you first open the app comes into mind.

What are the most suitable practices for achieving something like this? Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I opted for is to create a table with Core Data and store username and a mod5 representation of the password. Unfortunately everywhere I looked it showed that keychain only saves passwords for what it assumes to be the only user using the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sci-fi Hi-fi keychain utils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security), which is a sweet wrapper around Keychain. It allows storing passwords on a per-user and per-service basis. I'd advise storing your usernames somewhere (CoreData, maybe) and then querying through SFHF to see if the password's valid.